# Apply CSS margins to text only in div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I used jQuery to add an image and accompanying text to a div when that image is clicked. Now, I'd like to add more white space between the image&text. However, I don't know how to style the text without styling the image also. Your help is kindly appreciated. Just to clarify, `.imgDescription` contains the image.

```js
$('.imgDescription').click(function() {
  $('#expandservices').empty();
}).click(function() {
  $(this).clone().appendTo($('#expandservices'))
}).click(function() {
  var info = ['Weplay farmville!','Need help signing onto health.gov? We can take you through the process step by step securely','We can give you the ins and outs of navigating gmail, msn, hotmail and other email services','We can help you get those Hello Kitty slippers you saw online on your doorstep in a couple days ','We can help you research topics on Google','From iPads to Kindles, we have the expertise to make your device management a breeze'];

  $('#expandservices').append((info[$(this).index()-1]));
});
```

```css
#expandservices {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2 class="btn-primary">Learn More about Our Services</h2>
<div id="center">
  <br>
  <div class="imgDescription">
    <span><a href="#socialmedia">Social Media</a></span>
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <img src="pics/twitter.jpeg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="imgDescription">
    <span><a href="#healthcare">Healthcare</a></span>
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <img src="pics/health.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="imgDescription">
    <span><a href="#email">Email</a></span>
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <img src="pics/gmail.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="imgDescription">
    <span><a href="#socialmedia">Online Shopping</a></span>
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <img src="pics/amazon.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="imgDescription">
    <span><a href="#socialmedia">Web Browsing</a></span>
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <img src="pics/googling.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="imgDescription">
    <span><a href="#device">Devices</a></span>
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <img onClick="expanddevice()" src="pics/device.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Clicking on a div above will cause an explainer div to appear below. -->
<p id="expandservices"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `span` which contains the text to `div` and set `margin` for it.

Also for `.imgDescription` to give the groups more space.

```js
$('.imgDescription').click(function() {
  $('#expandservices').empty();
}).click(function() {
  $(this).clone().appendTo($('#expandservices'))
}).click(function() {
  var info = ['Weplay farmville!','Need help signing onto health.gov? We can take you through the process step by step securely','We can give you the ins and outs of navigating gmail, msn, hotmail and other email services','We can help you get those Hello Kitty slippers you saw online on your doorstep in a couple days ','We can help you research topics on Google','From iPads to Kindles, we have the expertise to make your device management a breeze'];

  $('#expandservices').append((info[$(this).index()-1]));
});
```

```css
#expandservices {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.imgDescription {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.imgText {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2 class="btn-primary">Learn More about Our Services</h2>
<div id="center">
  <br>
  <div class="imgDescription">
    <div class="imgText"><a href="#socialmedia">Social Media</a></div>
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <img src="pics/twitter.jpeg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="imgDescription">
    <div class="imgText"><a href="#healthcare">Healthcare</a></div>
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <img src="pics/health.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="imgDescription">
    <div class="imgText"><a href="#email">Email</a></div>
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <img src="pics/gmail.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="imgDescription">
    <div class="imgText"><a href="#socialmedia">Online Shopping</a></div>
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <img src="pics/amazon.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="imgDescription">
    <div class="imgText"><a href="#socialmedia">Web Browsing</a></div>
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <img src="pics/googling.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="imgDescription">
    <div class="imgText"><a href="#device">Devices</a></div>
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <img onClick="expanddevice()" src="pics/device.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Clicking on a div above will cause an explainer div to appear below. -->
<p id="expandservices"></p>
```